# Is it possible to use python http.server on a different IP?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, server

so currently if I start python http.server on windows 10, it automatically starts on localhost 127.0.0.1, and if I bind it it can only take my system's IP. But I want to start the http.server on a custome ip such as 100.65.0.83, is this possible by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to bind IP to `0.0.0.0` and open ports

Also it might be useful to check `http.server`:

```
python3 -m http.server --help
usage: server.py [-h] [--cgi] [--bind ADDRESS] [--directory DIRECTORY] [port]

positional arguments:
  port                  specify alternate port (default: 8000)

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --cgi                 run as CGI server
  --bind ADDRESS, -b ADDRESS
                        specify alternate bind address (default: all interfaces)
  --directory DIRECTORY, -d DIRECTORY
                        specify alternate directory (default: current directory)
```

So final command might be like:

```bash
python3 -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: this starts the python server on 0.0.0.0:8000, I want to start the server on 100.65.0.80:8000, how to do this?

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is a broadcast address, your server will be available through public or local IPs such as `100.65.0.80`

Comment: Also you could bind directly with `--bind 100.65.0.80`. If this helps, consider marking answer as accepted

Comment: But i cannot bind 100.65.0.80 unless I add 100.65 range in my network adapters as secondary ip. I don't want to add that in my network adapters and want to use this range regardless for testing purposes. how can i do that?